# How can we make this import one liner?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular-module

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UiCommonsModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([JobListEffect]),
    StoreModule.forFeature('job', jobTrackingListReducerMap),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([RoleManagementEffect]),
    StoreModule.forFeature('roleManagement', roleManagementReducerMap),
  ]
```

I want to make this EffectsModule and StoreModule in one line.

for effect I can do this:-

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([JobListEffect,RoleManagementEffect]),
```

What to do for store?

```
StoreModule.forFeature('job', jobTrackingListReducerMap),
StoreModule.forFeature('roleManagement', roleManagementReducerMap),
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://ngrx.io/api/store/StoreModule#forfeature), `StoreModule.forFeature` has 3 overloads and none of them take multiple features as an argument. So you can't do what you are trying to do with `StoreModule.forFeature`